# Replacing "name" attribute using Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got a form on a website with a bunch of input elements.  The name attribute for these elements is of the form "property-0".  However, the user may need multiple fieldsets just like the current one, so I clone the fieldset with jQuery clone(), but then I need to increment the number on the end.  The number could be above 10, so I can't just select the last character.

This is what I am trying:

```
name.replace(/([0-9]+)$/, String(Number('$1')+1));
```

but it just gives me `property-NaN`.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function in as the second argument to [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), like this:

```
name.replace(/([0-9]+)$/,function(a, m) { return +m+1; });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tYaNy/), feel free to replace `+m` with `parseInt(m, 10)` if you're mor comfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I never knew you could use a function there.

Answer (score 3):

You are converting the string '$1' to a number (it isn't), so it becomes NaN (Not a Number). You need to pass a callback function to `.replace()` instead:

```
name.replace(/([0-9]+)$/, function(str, p1) {
    return Number(p1) + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$1` like this. That only works if you put it directly into the replacement string or use a callback function.